# How to position an image at the center for any device?

Tags: html, css, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I am working on Phone gap. So,I need to give the code in a generic format so that it is applicable to any device.

I have a image with dimension with dimensions **2350*180**.

I have tried with these codes..

```
width: 100%;
top: 100%;
margin-top: 50%;
```

but,these is not at the center for various devices.

then I tried it with

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

then

```
display: block;
text-align: center;
```

then

```
<table>
    <tr style="vertical-align: middle;">
        <td id="main" style="width: 100%;">
            <img src="" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

For all the above CSS mentioned,my output---->**image sticks to the top margin to the top of the screen** as If I have given margin-top:0;

Please help me and correct me.

I have **2 more questions** with respect to this **big image**

Now, I have a background image

```
style="background:url("img/bg.png") no-repeat fixed center top; width:100%; height:100%; "
```

this code works for few  only.. Is there any mistake in my code?

2nd question, is when I scroll there is scroll bar thats visible.  SO I added

```
style="overflow:hidden;"

<img src=""/> tag.
```

am I correct or any other code should be added?

Comment: Is it possible for you to use the image as an actual background-image or does it have to be an `<img>`? Then you could use `background: url(/*image-path/img.png*/) no-repeat center center;`

Comment: I am using **MAPPING functionality** on that image. NOW, @kleinfreund please guide me whether can I use that as an background image?

Comment: You can't use image maps on a background-image. (I've tried something similar yesterday :<)

Comment: **Important:** Image maps won't work with a self resizing image, because you only can use *absolute* values with the coord-attribute on the area-element. *No* percentages are allowed there. Even in HTML5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works – don't forget to add an image-url to the src-attribute.
Also you just could use a div instead of your table.

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

img { 
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Note: If you have parent elements surrounding your table, you'll need to add `height: 100%;` to them as well.

Comment: @user This works. Try it with a new jsfiddle.net/codepen.io. If it is not working for you, you have something conflicting with it in your code.

Comment: @user If you have other elements as parents of your table (e.g. a div), you'll need to add `height: 100%;` to them as well.

Comment: Perfect judgement. I got it

Comment: require your suggestions on the edit version of this question.

Comment: @user Please aks new questions in, well, a new question. ;)

Comment: your help required [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957030/how-to-position-a-background-for-a-big-image)

Answer (score 4):

Add `max-width:100%` to image and place it in the table of `height:100%`

```
body, html{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
table{
    height:100%;
    background:#fffad6;
}
img{
    max-width:100%;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ztru7/1/)**

Comment: Won't you need `height: auto;` on the img as well to keep proportions as the screen resizes?

Comment: @kleinfreund NO. max-width wil take care of that

Comment: You're right. But with your code alone, the image isn't centered horicontally. You'll need `width: 100%;` on the table along with `text-align: center;`

Comment: @Sowmya,but your suggested code is making no difference to my output :-( any other suggestions...??... It is still at the top of the device

Comment: @user Try adding the styles from my comment to your table: `table { width: 100%; text-align: center; }`

Comment: @user Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Ztru7/3/. Hope you can identify the differences in the fiddle. Since you have included so many unwanted elements it is difficult to explain

Comment: @Sowmya require your suggestions on the edit version of this question.

Comment: @user Your inline body style was wrong and `.html` doesn't make any sense. Importantly there was no `height:100%` specified for parent div.

Comment: @Sowmya your help required [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957030/how-to-position-a-background-for-a-big-image)

Answer (score 2):

I did a bit digging around and this what I came up width to center a image both horizontal and vertical: http://jsfiddle.net/jdtjk/2/

CSS:

```
.middle{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto; 
}
```

Html:

```
<div>
    <img src="*" class="middle" />
</div>
```

Edit:

Changed so image downscales to fit window size:
http://jsfiddle.net/jdtjk/5/

Changes to CSS:

```
.middle{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto; 
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

If you want to limit the up/downscale can you use min-width min-height properties in css. If you want to upscale the image can you change the max properties.

Comment: This centers the image as well, right. But if the window is smaller as the image itself, it won't resize. Although I'm not sure if this is necessary.

Comment: Check the edited answer and link to JS fiddler now :) This should resize the image to fit the screen.