# how to position a background for a big image which is centered at the center of the page?

Tags: html, css, cordova, media-queries, cordova-2.0.0

I have a image with dimension with dimensions **2350*180**.

I am working on Phone gap. So,I need to give the code in a generic format so that it is applicable to any device.

Now, I have a background image for that big image.

```
style="background:url("img/bg.png") no-repeat fixed center top; width:100%; height:100%; "
```

this code works for few  only.. Is there any mistake in my code?

**another question**, is when I scroll there is scroll bar thats visible.  SO I added

```
style="overflow:hidden;"

<img src=""/> tag.
```

Am I correct or any other code should be added?

**EDIT:**

**HTML**

```
    <body style="style="background:url("img/bg.png") no-repeat fixed center top; width:100%; height:100%;" class="body">
    <div id="image"  class="noSelect">
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <td class="main">
                    <img src="http://www.rhpstudio.com/images/google_icon.png" alt="map" usemap="#map" style="overflow:hidden;" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</body>
```

I am taking about this background **background:url("img/bg.png")** in the code, and this image given here in  is a  sample one BUT its dimension is **2350*180**.

**EDIT:2-->entire code**

**HTML CODE:**

```
<body style="background-image:url(img/bg.png);" class="body">
    <div id="image"  class="noSelect" style="height:100%;">
       <table class="table">
          <tr>
        <td class="main">
           <img src="img/list.png" alt="bloodtestmap" usemap="#bloodtestmap" class="noSelect" style="overflow:hidden;" />
         </td>
          </tr>
       </table>
```

**CSS CODE:**

```
    .body, .main_html
    {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .body
    {
        overflow: hidden;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
    .table 
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .main 
    { 
        max-width: 100%;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now set a background image to stretch to the edges of the container in various ways. If you don't mind the image distorting, you would do it like this:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Rather than this (which is broken)

```
style="style="background:url("img/bg.png") no-repeat fixed center top; width:100%; height:100%;"
```

try this in your style sheet:

```
body {
    background-image:url("img/bg.png");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: OK, see my revised answer.

Comment: this background has a design so keeps on repeating. when I give this `no-repeat fixed center top; width:100%; height:100%;`. the background is fixed and only the image scrolls. **What should i do to avoid the scrollbar**

Comment: You seem to be ignoring my suggestions, so I don't know what to say. I don't understand what you are doing. I guess you could use `body {overflow: hidden;}` but that's usually a disastrous move.

Comment: No Sir.I have followed the suggestion and that is when i noticed that the design of the background is repeating. I would prefer if it was in the same position allowing the image alone to scroll

Comment: Could you show us an example of what you are doing? Or at least post the code you have now?

Comment: Sir, Please find the edit 2 version which has the entire html code and their respective CSS.